# Draw multiple circles inside multiple squares with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to draw multiple circles inside multiple squares like in the picture below:

[image]

I only managed to draw multiple circles inside each other and multiple squares inside each other but cannot figure out how to place them as it is on the picture

This is what I have currently

```js
function drawSquare() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("Square");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var square = canvas.getContext("2d");

    square.fillStyle = "red";
    square.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

    square.fillStyle = "yellow";
    square.fillRect(50, 50, 400, 400);

    square.fillStyle = "blue";
    square.fillRect(100, 100, 300, 300);

  }
}



function drawRedCircle() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("Circle");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var circle = canvas.getContext("2d");

    circle.beginPath();
    circle.arc(250, 250, 125, 0, Math.PI * 2, );
    circle.fillStyle = "red";
    circle.fill();
    circle.stroke();
    circle.closePath();

    circle.beginPath();
    circle.arc(250, 250, 75, 0, Math.PI * 2, );
    circle.fillStyle = "yellow";
    circle.fill();
    circle.stroke();
    circle.closePath();


    circle.beginPath();
    circle.arc(250, 250, 25, 0, Math.PI * 2, );
    circle.fillStyle = "blue";
    circle.fill();
    circle.stroke();
    circle.closePath();
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="Square" width="500" height="500" style="border: 5px solid #FF0000;">
Your browser does not support the Canvas tag. </canvas>
```

Could someone please advise me on how to places these circles inside the squares? Pretty please

Comment: What's with the face? xD

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález perhaps a screencrop nuisance, no?!

Comment: You have to think in a canvas being like layers. You draw a rectangle, on top of that the next smaller circle/rectangle, on top of that the next smaller circle/rectrangle, and so on. The API is pretty straightforward if you read it: just size and position and an API to fill the rect or the stroke. For example in your code you have `stroke()`, which strokes a line, and if you want to actually fill the inside, you should use `fill()` instead. As I said, is pretty straightforward.

Comment: `var canvas = document.getElementById("Circle");` but you don't have such a selector Element in the DOM. Use the `Square` instead, or just rename it to `id="canvas"` and use `document.getElementById("canvas");` for both.

Comment: Also, don't hardcode stuff into your functions, instead make a reusable function and call it multiple times with different arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Just put everything on one canvas.

Currently, you code says, get a canvas with an id of square and put squares on it.  Then get a canvas with an id of circle and put circles on it.  Instead, just use one canvas and draw both the squares and circles on it.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

function draw() {
  ctx.fillStyle="red";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

  ctx.fillStyle="yellow";
  ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 400, 400);

  ctx.fillStyle="blue";
  ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 300, 300);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(250, 250, 125, 0, Math.PI * 2,);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(250, 250, 75, 0, Math.PI * 2,);
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(250, 250, 25, 0, Math.PI * 2,);
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
    
}

draw()
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 5px solid #FF0000;">
Your browser does not support the Canvas tag. </canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use a single ID selector like `id="square"` on your canvas Element
- Don't hardcode variables inside functions, instead create two **reusable functions** and call them by passing different argument values i.e: `const drawSquare = (xCenter, yCenter, size, color) => {`

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector `#canvas`.getContext `2d`;

const drawSquare = (xCenter, yCenter, size, color) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = color ?? "#000";
  ctx.fillRect(xCenter - size / 2, yCenter - size / 2, size, size);
  ctx.closePath();
};

const drawRedCircle = (xCenter, yCenter, radius, color) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(xCenter, yCenter, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = color ?? "#000";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
};

// Draw!

drawSquare(250, 250, 500, "red");
drawSquare(250, 250, 400, "yellow");
drawSquare(250, 250, 300, "blue");

drawRedCircle(250, 250, 125, "red");
drawRedCircle(250, 250,  75, "yellow");
drawRedCircle(250, 250,  25, "blue");
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
Your browser does not support the Canvas tag. </canvas>
```